# Finding unique codes based on lowest values

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I've been trying to find a solution to this for a long time in many places and couldn't find it.

Here's a description:

I have a table of changeover times between products. I'd like to create a list that picks the lowest C/O time for the next position but without repeating products. Assume that the first item on the list is picked "by hand".

So, using the example attached, this list could look like this:

A
B
D
E

You'll see that for the last position I had to ignore B and A because they were already picked. Could someone please help me with figuring out the formula for it?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I don't have access to Office 365 at work, just 2016.

[Example Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BR73.png)

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   -   10  20  10  -
B   -   -   -   10  15
C   20  -   -   15  10
D   15  10  20  -   15
E   -   20  15  10  -
```

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: Why do you stop at E? Surely the next product after that is C, at which point you have then included all your products and, in a repetitive environment would add changeover C to A to complete the cycle. The problem then has a lot of similarities to the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP), except the TSP aims to minimise the sum of changeover times across the cycle and this is not necessarily the same as picking the minimum changeover time (and avoiding product petition) at each stage.

Comment: I'm never going through all items, the list has an arbitrary end to it. I'm not worried about stopping, this part is trivial. It's making sure the codes are unique is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, interesting problem. Imagine first you can pick again previously picked items.

First find the range to search for a minimum based on the picked by hand first item (*firstitem*):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(firstitem,$A$2:$A$6,0),)
```

If *firstitem* is "A" this would return an array {-,10,20,10,-}.

Now find the minimum in that array (say in cell G2):

```
=MIN(INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(firstitem,$A$2:$A$6,0),))
```

and then the index position for that minimum (say in cell H2):

```
=MATCH(G2,INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(firstitem,$A$2:$A$6,0),),0)
```

and its corresponding name (say in cell I2):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,H2)
```

Now you can repeat the next row, instead referring I2 rather than *firstitem*

To ignore previous selected items, we must propagate a mask that modifies the search array in each step above. The  mask will be a row 1,1,1,1,1 in the begin, then becomes 1,0,1,1,1 if say "B" was selected. Use MINIFS to filter the masks in K2:O2

```
=MINIFS(INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(firstitem,$A$2:$A$6,0),),K2:O2,1)
```

and

```
=MATCH(G2,INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(firstitem,$A$2:$A$6,0),)*K2:O2,0)
```

Comment: It worked! I found a way around the lack of MINIFS and it appears to be doing exactly what it's supposed to. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, what was the work around if you don't have MINIFS?

Comment: The mask is under the table, let's say the codes are listed in column A, starting with A8. I needed the mask to show only viable options, so B7:F7 code was something like this: 
=IF(B$1="-",0,1)
(I'm simplifying here, I needed to make it a bit more complex to account for different lines of production but the gist is here)

Then, from B8 to Fwhatever the code is as follows:
=IF($A8=B$1,0,B7)

I'm sorry I don't know how to edit code.